# Microsoft Lync messenger download size?

Tags: lync

Im trying to download microsoft lync messenger. The download size is about 1.5 gb.
Is this the correct size for a messenger?

Or is there a lite version for this program with smaller size?

Thanks..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is quite large. If you just want the trial client you can find the 32-bit version [here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=5484) and the 64-bit version [here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=10400). Both are ~50mb.